# Advanced right click functionality - click and hold, show buttons, on release click what is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse

How would you do this in javascript/jquery?

I currently have the `right-click + hold` to show a div, and then it disappears on the release of the right click. However, I would like to click any button the mouse is hovered over on the release of the right click.

This is what I have so far:

```
// Cancel out the default context menu
$('body').on('contextmenu', function(){
    return false;
});

$("body").on('mousedown', function(event){
    // If it's not a right click, return
    if (event.which != 3) 
        return;

    // Set div coordinates to clicked point
    $('div').css({
        'top': event.pageY,
        'left': event.pageX
    });

    $('div').show();
});    

$("body").on('mouseup', function(event){
    // If it's not a right click, return
    if (event.which != 3)
        return;

    $('div').hide();
});
```

Comment: Don't forget `mouseout` in case the user holds down the right click, but moves the cursor outside of the browser window and then lets go of the button. (it would do the same as `mouseup` in your case, I think.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching the `mouseup` event handler to the buttons.

Comment: I tried this initially with no luck in my application. But my problem wasn't the events, it was the z-index of the element! The element I was trying to hover over had a lower z-index than the background behind it. So no click events were registering. Provided that the z-index is correct, this is the correct answer to the question I asked.